# Pass data through router to other component in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to pass data through router. My code is working but it shows data in url. I don't want that like as POST method.**url should like /data-list** . Also I want to catch passing value from component. Here I did not use vuex . Actually my job is to show message that task is done based on this data. I am using Laravel for backend. Thanks in advance

1st component

```
axios.post("/request/data", dataform).then(function (resp) {
  app.$router.push({ path: "/data-list/" + resp.data.success });
});
```

routes

```
{
  path: '/data-list/:message?',
  name: 'dataList',
  component: dataList,
  meta: {
      auth: true
  }
},
```

Another component. Here I want to catch

```
mounted() {
  var app = this;
  app.message = app.$route.params.message;
}
```

Comment: When you say "data in url",  What do you mean exactly?
You just want the path always be `/data-list`?

Comment: exactly i want the path always be /data-list  . I am tried for long time

Comment: But `:message` is dynamic tag, do you want same component rendered irrespective what data you fetch?

Comment: I want to fetch in other component. it should be path: '/data-list

Comment: What do you want to fetch?
Is other component --> dataList?

Comment: I want to fetch resp.data.success value in dataList component

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you are fetching data in some component and then you are doing a router-push to `dataList` component.

You want to access the data in `dataList` component.

Since you always want the route to be `/dataList`, do this in your `routes` file

```
{
  path: '/data-list', //removing dynamic tag.
  name: 'dataList',
  component: dataList,
  meta: {
      auth: true
  }
```

},

Then in the component where you do router push, add a `handleClick` like so.

```
handleClick() {
      let data = {
        id: 25,
        description: "pass data through params"
      };
      this.$router.push({
        name: "dataList", //use name for router push
        params: { data }
      });
    }
  }
```

Then in your `dataList` component you can access the data passed in the `mounted` like so :

```
mounted() {
    let data = this.$route.params.data;
    console.log("data is", data);
  }
```

Working implementation attached below.

[image: Edit Vue Routing Example]

Comment: Thanks for reply. Showing this **Cannot read property '$router' of undefined**

Comment: Did you try opening the codesandbox that I shared?
Are you facing the error on codesandbox?

Comment: In mounted it is `route` not `router`.

Comment: writing this in case someone else reaches here trying to send objects with router on Vue3 [router doesn't support passing objects](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/issues/494#issuecomment-698951187) even though it worked before

Answer (score 5):

You can push router data in router like this.

```
this.$router.push({
            name: "dataList",
            params: { data: resp.data },
});
```

and in the routes you can define your route as

```
{
      path: "/dataList",
      name: "dataList",
      props: true,
      meta: { title: "Data list" },
      component: () => import("path to datalist component")
    },
```

and in the DataList.vue you can use props to get the data

```
export default {
 props:['data'],
 mounted(){
   alert(this.data);
 }
}
```

Comment: I am beginner . can you please  tell me to get data as alert in mounted() as i mentioned ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Showing this **Cannot read property '$router' of undefined**